# What fish function controls completion of filenames, and how can I change it?

Tags: autocomplete, fish

I am trying to alter the standard logic used by `fish` to find filename completions.  In particular, I want `fish` not to consider any filename that ends in a tilde (`~`) character, as these are emacs backup files and are not interesting.

I had assumed that the list of possible completions would be provided by a `fish` function, which I could then edit to remove the ones ending in tildes.  But I cannot find the function.  I have looked in the documentation at fishshell.com, and I have also tried `functions | grep complete`.  What function should I be editing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike most completions file name completions is not implemented as a function; it's baked into the C++ code. See the `completer_t::complete_param_expand()` method in src/complete.cpp. If you can make a cogent argument for how this type of customization would be implemented I'd encourage you to [open an issue](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/new).

P.S., Note that `functions` will not show private functions unless you invoke it as `functions -a`. I mention this because many completion functions are marked private by beginning their name with an underscore.